# Sending base64binary (image) via SOAP with ruby / savon

Tags: php, ruby, soap, savon

I'm using SOAP api for allegro.pl (polish alternative for ebay.com) and I've a litte problem with sending images through SOAP. I was asking the same question at official forum but unfortunately no-one has replied.

Anyway, working (piece of) code (soap message) in PHP looks like that:

```
array(
'fid' => 16,
'fvalueImage' => file_get_contents('http://www.stropna_www.pl/images/obrazek.jpg')
```

*note this is not a full soap message, but this one which made me not sleeping this night*

And it works (well, in documentation it works, I cannot be sure as I do not use PHP (neither do I know it)). **I was looking for equivalent for file_get_contents** in ruby and I was trying to use net/http and open-uri to open file from the url and even tried to use

```
img = File.open('img.jpg', 'rb') { |f| f.read }
```

but every time I try, server returns invalid XML.

**When I try to send the request without image it works correctly.**

---

Here's the full code in Ruby:

```
def self.do_new_auction_ext 
img = File.open('img.jpg', 'rb') { |f| f.read }

xml_message = prepare_message("DoNewAuctionExtRequest", {
  :sessionHandle => self.session_id,
  :fields => [
    { :fid => 1,                                # Tytuł
      :fvalueString => "Oferta Testowa ze zdjeciem", },       # TODO: Zmienne?
    { :fid => 2,                                # Kategoria
      :fvalueInt => 1834 },                       # TODO: Zmienne?
    { :fid => 4,                                # Czas trwania
      :fvalueInt => 3 },                          # 1 - 3 dni, 2 - 7 dni, 3 - 10 dni
    { :fid => 5,                                # Ilość
      :fvalueInt => 12},                          # TODO: Zmienne?
    { :fid => 8,                                # Cena kup teraz
      :fvalueFloat => 50.00},                     # TODO: Zmienne?
    { :fid => 9,                                # Kraj
      :fvalueInt => 228},                         # 1 - Polska, 228 - Neverland
    { :fid => 10,                               # Wojewodztwo
      :fvalueInt => 215},                         # Lewopolskie
    { :fid => 11,                               # Miejscowość
      :fvalueString => "Bielsko-Biala"},
    { :fid => 14,                               # Formy platnosci
      :fvalueInt => 1 },                          # Płatne z góry przelewem
    { :fid => 16,                               # Zdjecie 1
      :fvalueString => img },
    #{ :fid => 15,                               # Opcje dodatkowe
    #  :fvalueInt => 2},
    { :fid => 24,                               # Opis
      :fvalueString => "konik"},
    { :fid => 28,                               # Sztuki / Komplety / Pary
      :fvalueInt => 1},
    { :fid => 32,                               # Kod pocztowy
      :fvalueString => "43-300"},
    { :fid => 35,                               # Darmowe opcje przesylki
      :fvalueInt => 2}                          # 1 - Odbior osobisty, 2 - e-mail, 4 - Odbior osobisty po przedplacie
  ]
})

# puts xml_message

response = @client.call(:do_new_auction_ext) do
  xml xml_message
end
```

*don't mind polish comments*

prepare_message function only creates xml which goes to the server, and I'm quite sure it's working correctly as w/o image the server responds as it should (it works!)

but, with the image sent the server responded with

```
{:fault=>{:faultcode=>"Sender", :faultstring=>"Invalid XML"}}
```

and here is [website with working PHP code](http://wrzasq.pl/blog/allegro-webapi-tutorial-vol-2.html) *website is in polish, but code is in PHP*

and lastly, [here is the documentation](http://allegro.pl/webapi/documentation.php/show/id,113) *it's also in polish, but includes english naming and additional PHP code under "Przykłady wywołań" tab*

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 and savon to send all SOAP request (which works, but sending the image doesn't).

---

Apologies for the wall of text but I was trying to explain this best I can. 
Thanks in advance for any help, and thank you even for reading this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try to encode the image content like:

`Base64.encode64(File.binread('path_to_your_file')`